# Что значит ошибка "SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Я совсем новичок)
Пишу в IDLE (Python 3.4.1 shell) Когда копирую код из интернета, он ошибки не выдаёт, а когда я его переписываю буква в букву, он выдаёт ошибку.
вот код из интернета:

```
>>>for i in 'hello world':
             if i == 'o':
                 continue
             print(i * 2, end='')
```

Вот мой:

```
>>> for i in 'hello world':
            if i == 'o':
                continue
            print(i * 2, end='')
```

> SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

В чём ошибка?

Оказывается ошибка была не только в отступах.
Если в питоне вы не правильно написали какую то строчку и после неё нажали Enter, то после этого программа может вместо переноса на новую строчку прогнать программу. Когда у меня такое было, я что бы избежать прогона вместо исправления ошибки переходил на новую строчку долгим нажатием на пробел, а уже потом исправлял ошибку. В результате программа видела не отступ, а длинную строчку. И выдавала ошибку! Спасибо всем большое. Ошибка устранена.
НА вопрос в коментарии: Я учусь по смоучителю в интернете https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python

Comment: отступы должны быть одинаковой длины - или 4 пробела (стандарт) или 8

Comment: Текст ошибки понятен?

Comment: По какому учебнику вы учитесь?

Comment: Нельзя смешивать табы и пробелы при создании отступов. Либо то, либо другое.

Comment: знаете, я вам порекомендую использовать либо wing ide как альтернатива idle, либо notepade++. первый из них вам поможет не путать табы и пробелы (он сам заменит таб на пробел), а второй поможет разобрать где есть таб а где есть пробел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В программировании на Питоне, отступы критичны!
Они используются языком для создания структуры программы (исходного кода).

Не стоит смешивать пробелы и табы.
А также надо следить за тем, чтобы отступы были все одинаковые и желательно кратные (например, по 4 пробела).

Comment: **Возможно** смешивать пробелы и табы (хотя это не хорошая практика). **Не надо**, чтобы отступы были все кратные. Важное только, чтобы **на одной и тот же самой уровне были одинаковыми** (например 2 табы + один пробель + 3 табы) . (Да, опять не самая лучшая практика.)

Answer (score 2):

На взгляд обе эти коды одинаковыми, но во вашем коде вы в команде

```
            if i == 'o':
```

использовали 1 <kbd>Tab</kbd> и 8 пробелов, пока в команде

```
            print(i * 2, end='')
```

вы использовали 12 пробелов.

Дла человека в том нет разницы (т.к. <kbd>Tab</kbd> видит как 4 пробели), но Питону это не нравится.