# Не пойму откуда проблема в пайтон

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pyowm 

while 1==1:

#
    owm = pyowm.OWM('a4ea03b972cd7dcf1cbb3395ab746f73' ,language='ru')




    place1 = str(input('Вкаком гораде нужнa погда:'))





    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place1)
    w = observation.get_weather()




    pogo = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
    pogo1 = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp_max']

    print('В городе ' + place1 + ' сейчас ' + w.get_detailed_status())



    H = 55

    print('Приблизительна температура сейчас в ' + place1 + ' Гдето '+ str(pogo)+' а максимальна за день'+ str(pogo1))




    if pogo < 1 and  w.get_detailed_status()=="снег":
        print( "Сейчас оченьььь холодно одевайся очень тепло на улеце снег" )
    elif pogo < 1 :
        print( "Сейчас оченьььь холодно одевайся очень тепло " ) 
    elif pogo < 9:
        print( "Cейчас холодно одевайся по лутше" )
    elif pogo < 9 and  w.get_detailed_status()=="дождь":
        print( "Cейчас холодно одевайся по лутше одевай дождевик на улеце дождь" )
    elif pogo < 20:
        print("Одевайся  чучуть по теплише")
    elif pogo < 20 and  w.get_detailed_status() =="дождь":
        print("Одевайся  чучуть по теплише и одевай дождевик на улеце дождь")
    elif pogo > 20:
        print("Одевайся как хочеш на улеце тепло")

    elif pogo > 20 and  w.get_detailed_status()=='дождь':
        print("Одевай дождевик или зонтик на улеце дождь но тепло")
```

Comment: У вас где-то пробелы используются, а где-то табуляция... Надо везде пробелы в начале строк

Comment: И еще вам надо поработать над русским языком, орфографией и пунктуацией. Иначе пользователи вашей программы будут шокированы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит ошибка "SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853288/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-syntaxerror-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentati)

Answer (score 0):

В python соблюдение отступов критически важно. Следует использовать одинаковый тип отступа и не мешать пробелы с табами (лучше вообще табы не использовать). Для человека визуально никакой разницы, но python ругается. А вообще существует такая штука как PEP 8 https://pep8.ru/doc/pep8/, - эдакий стайлгайд написания кода на Питоне, все стараются его придерживаться.

```
import pyowm

while 1 == 1:
    owm = pyowm.OWM('a4ea03b972cd7dcf1cbb3395ab746f73' ,language='ru')

    place1 = str(input('Вкаком гораде нужнa погда:'))

    observation = owm.weather_at_place(place1)
    w = observation.get_weather()

    pogo = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
    pogo1 = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp_max']

    print('В городе ' + place1 + ' сейчас ' + w.get_detailed_status())

    H = 55

    print('Приблизительна температура сейчас в ' + place1 + ' Гдето '+ str(pogo)+' а максимальна за день'+ str(pogo1))

    if pogo < 1 and  w.get_detailed_status()=="снег":
        print( "Сейчас оченьььь холодно одевайся очень тепло на улеце снег" )
    elif pogo < 1 :
        print( "Сейчас оченьььь холодно одевайся очень тепло " )
    elif pogo < 9:
        print( "Cейчас холодно одевайся по лутше" )
    elif pogo < 9 and  w.get_detailed_status() == "дождь":
        print( "Cейчас холодно одевайся по лутше одевай дождевик на улеце дождь" )
    elif pogo < 20:
        print("Одевайся  чучуть по теплише")
    elif pogo < 20 and  w.get_detailed_status() == "дождь":
        print("Одевайся  чучуть по теплише и одевай дождевик на улеце дождь")
    elif pogo > 20:
        print("Одевайся как хочеш на улеце тепло")
    elif pogo > 20 and  w.get_detailed_status() == 'дождь':
        print("Одевай дождевик или зонтик на улеце дождь но тепло")
```

Ну и орфографию бы подтянуть не помешало)

Answer (score 0):

Проверки python файлов для таких ошибок:

```
python -m tabnanny <name of python file>
```