# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python

Никак не пойму где ошибка с табуляцией. Пересчитал уже все пробелы где только можно и где нельзя. Помогите слепому(

```
if not arr:
    return 0
else:
    for i in arr:
        if i > 0:
            break;
    else:
        return 0;

max_sum = 0
for chain_len in range(1, len(arr)):
    for first in arr[:1 - chain_len]:
        new_sum = sum(arr[first:first + chain_len])
        if new_sum > maxi:
            max_sum = new_sum


return max_sum
```

Comment: У вас некоторые отступы пробелами, а некоторые табами. Так нельзя.

Comment: Текст ошибки переводится "непоследовательное использование табов и пробелов в отступах". Про неправильное количество тут речи нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что значит ошибка "SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853288/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-syntaxerror-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentati)

Answer (score 1):

В python2 можно было использовать и табы и пробелы одновременно, а для проверки исполлзовался запуск с  флагом -t. В python3 этого делать категорически нельзя. Либо табы, либо пробелы.

Answer (score 0):

> if not arr:

Подозреваю что в этой строке:

> [image: скриншот поиска]

А вообще, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> в редакторе никто не отменял.

Comment: В редакторах кода, например sublime или pycharm, можно установить настройку которая покажет тип отступа.

Comment: @alex, тоже можно, но мне как-то ctrl+f проще.